# How to make the card scrollable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to acheive this UI in flutter.

[image]

I have achieved the top portion of appbar and the 1st Card. The second card needs to be scrollable. I'm newbie to flutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the second card into a `SingleChildScrollView` ([docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html))?

> A box in which a single widget can be scrolled. This widget is useful when you have a single box that will normally be entirely visible, for example a clock face in a time picker, but you need to make sure it can be scrolled if the container gets too small in one axis (the scroll direction).

Comment: Yeah I tried but covers the whole screen. Can you do that for me?

Comment: Can you try putting all of the cards in a container (`Column` for ex) and wrapping the third one in a `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: Nice! Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

use singlechildscrollview...

[read more about singlechildscrollview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

Comment: Yeah I tried but covers the whole screen. Can you do that for me?